# Do I need to downgrade from 2.6 to EhCache 2.5 when I want simple persistency?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I've EhCache 2.6.Now I wanted to enable persistency (e.g. to reuse the cache after restart). But I've noticed I can't with 2.6 - see [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/fast-restart#compatibility-with-previous-versions)

So I would need either the 'distributed' persistence with terracotta (not an option as we would like to keep it simple) or using the enterprise version. Do I really need to downgrade to 2.5 in order to use simple persistency?

Comment: are you able to use persistency with 2.10.x or anything after 2.6.x of EhCache ? From latest docs, I see restartable is enabled only for enterprise version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but the link is pretty clear that the old behavior is still available.

> After upgrading, however, it is not mandatory to add the 
>   sub-element. In Ehcache 2.6, disk persistence configuration elements
>   from previous Ehcache versions will continue to be available with the
>   same functionality, as long as the  sub-element has not
>   been specified.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I missed that but somehow it still does not work .. hmmh have to figure that out

Comment: Hmmh, listener didn't work out, the system property didn't work ... so I used my own shutdown thread via Runtime.addShutdownhook and it worked :) !